# how to draw gtk widget (like buttons) in the firefox npapi plugin under linux?

Tags: widget, gtk, npapi

I has known how to write a simple npapi plugin. But now I am in troubles to draw some buttons in the plugin.

I download a simple sample named webp-npapi (link: code.google.com/p/webp-npapi-linux/) and modify it, it now can work well in my firefox. It is a windowless plugin that can show webp format image.

I also download a complex sample named npapi-vlc (link: git.videolan.org/?p=npapi-vlc.git;a=summary) and has read it. after compile, it also work well in my firefox. This plugin has draw some gtk buttons while it is as a window type plugin.

I want to draw some buttons in my own plugin, so I imitate the codes of npapi-vlc to modify webp-npapi. I change the type of webp-npapi from windowless to window by comment the following codes in constructor of CPlugin class: 
(http://code.google.com/p/webp-npapi-linux/source/browse/trunk/CPlugin.cpp)

```
/* 
    // Make sure we can render this plugin 
    NPBool browserSupportsWindowless = false; 
    s_pBrowserFunctions->getvalue(instance, NPNVSupportsWindowless, &browserSupportsWindowless); 
    if( !browserSupportsWindowless ) 
            throw std::runtime_error("Windowless mode not supported by the browser"); 
    s_pBrowserFunctions->setvalue(instance, NPPVpluginWindowBool, (void*) false); 
*/
```

then I start draw a button in CPlugin::setWindow() function：

```
NPError CPlugin::setWindow(const NPWindow * const window) 
{ 
    #ifdef WEBPNPAPI_DEBUG 
    printf("CPlugin::setWindow() - Window set\n"); 
    #endif 

    m_window = *window; 

    //I add these codes to draw a button 
    printf("test start\n"); 
    GdkColor color_bg; 
    gdk_color_parse("#AAAAAA", &color_bg); 

    Window socket = (Window)m_window.window; 
    GtkWidget *parent = gtk_plug_new(socket); 
    gtk_widget_modify_bg(parent, GTK_STATE_NORMAL, &color_bg); 
    GtkWidget *button = gtk_button_new_with_label("hello"); 
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(parent), button); 
    gtk_widget_show_all(parent); 
    printf("test end\n"); 

    GtkRequisition req; 
    req.width = m_window.width; 
    req.height = m_window.height; 
    gtk_widget_size_request(parent, &req); 

    return NPERR_NO_ERROR; 
}
```

But, It doesn't show anything in the webpage...

So I really want to know why it doesn't work and what is the most important things you must notice when you want to draw some gtk widget in your plugin?

thx!

Answer (score 2):

I almost despair after several days research, but today I finally successfully resovle it. I now can draw a gtk button in the plugin.

The keypoint is that you must write following codes in the NPP_GetValue() funciton:

```
case NPPVpluginNeedsXEmbed: 
    *((bool *)value) = true; 
    return NPERR_NO_ERROR;
```

Notice: these codes can't be wrote in NP_GetValue() function, it's no useful. 
This is the mistake that I did before.

This is the only document I can find in the internet:
https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/XEmbed_Extension_for_Mozilla_Plugins

And a simple sample about XEmbed:
http://multimedia.cx/diamondx/